# Rails find the id of an associated controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a belongs_to association, where months belongs_to wallpaper. The Months table has a column called :wallpaper_id which is being used to get the id of the Wallpaper.

months_controller:
  @wallpaper = Wallpaper.find(:wallpaper_id => params[:wallpaper_id])
  @month = @wallpaper.months.find(params[:id])

But I get an error: Unknown key(s): wallpaper_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@wallpaper = Wallpaper.find(params[:wallpaper_id])
@month = @wallpaper.months.find(params[:id])
```

or

```
@month = Month.where(:wallpaper_id => params[:wallpaper_id], :id => params[:id])
```